# Will it be possible to see the mixin number with ringct on?

Tags: ringct, ringsize

I was thinking if it was true you could see mixin number with ringct transaction? thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be possible to see. Consider that you're submitting `n` one-time public keys in each transaction, where one of them belongs to you and others are decoys. There's really no way to hide this. Mixin is the number of those decoys used in a transaction, so mixin = `n-1`.

Major change with ringCT, apart from hiding the amounts, will be reduced number of outputs per transaction.

For example, currently when sending 123xmr, it would be split into denominations of 100, 20, and 3. Each of them would then be obfuscated with 4 decoy outputs resulting in total of 15 outputs in a single transaction. RingCT will bring this down to 5, as 123xmr could be used as it is, without splitting, because the amount will be hidden.